# Removing my site's AMP results from search engines?

Tags: amp-html

I used WordPress's AMP plugin to convert my site to AMP.  After a few weeks I uninstalled it.

Now, when people search for my site on Google, they see an AMP link, click on it and get a 500 error.

If they use the “Click here to continue” they get redirected to a 404 page! Why? Because `example.com/post/amp` doesn’t exist.

Is there a way to tell Google - or other search engines - not to suggest my old AMP pages?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

**1. Wait for Google to figure it out over subsequent crawls of your page.**

If you don't want to do any work, the good news is that eventually Google will figure it out and your AMP page links will disappear from search results. HOWEVER, this can take over a month and lead to a bad user experience for anyone who clicks the expired links.

**2. Update your 404 page.**

In the meantime, you can make your AMP pages 404 and include a link to the non-AMP version of your content with a message about why this is happening for the user.

**3. Tell Google those pages no longer exist**

Follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping) to tell Google to remove page content from the AMP cache. This will happen faster than simply letting Google figure it out but can be more time intensive since you have to do it manually for each individual page URL. There is not currenly a way to invalidate the whole domain.

In your terminal you can do something like this for each page you want to remove:

```
curl https://cdn.ampproject.org/update-ping/c/s/ampbyexample.com
```

This would send an update-ping for content formerly served at this URL (note the added 'update-ping'):

```
https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/ampbyexample.com
```

You can also visit the update-ping URL in your browser for each page on your site. You won't see anything, but the request should still be processed.

Comment: Are you sure that serving a 404 is a correct response if one wants to force an update to Google's AMP cache?

Comment: This is my suggestion if you don't want to manually force the update for each of your amp pages

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow the instruction from [docs](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping), section "Remove AMP content".

Answer (score -1):

To remove your site from Google AMP cache, you may want to try [Update AMP Content](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping). As stated,

> For urgent removals, it's preferable to serve an error over serving cached content that no longer exists. When you remove content from your server that's also stored in the Google AMP Cache, use the ["update-ping" mechanism](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-ping#update-ping-format) to permanently remove the content from the cache.

It might also help if you check and follow the simple steps to derive the original URL from its cached version given in [How-to for search engines](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1V_uLHoa48IlbFl7_3KWT_1JmCf6BnFtt3S_oR4UsasQ/edit#).

Comment: I *am* serving a 404 error. I have been for a week. But Google is still presenting those results.